# counting array with both integer and string keys

Tags: php

```
echo count(array("1" => "A", 1 => "B", "C", 2 => "D"));
```

This outputs 2. I've played around with it and noticed that PHP identifies both string numbers and integers the same when used as keys in an array. Seems like integers are prioritized. Also when I var_dump the array only elements containing the value "B" and "D" are displayed. I understand why "A" is not displayed but why is "C" not in the var_dump?

Comment: You array declaration is just a shorter way of this: `array("1" => "A", 1 => "B", 2=>"C", 2 => "D")`. So it is absolutely natural to have an array of only 2 elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is basically being built as follows:

```
Key "1" is an integer-like string, treat as integer 1
Assign "A" to key 1
Assign "B" to key 1 (overwrite "A")
No explicit key, take greatest key so far and add 1 = 2
Assign "C" to key 2
Assign "D" to key 2 (overwrite "C")
```

Thus your resulting array is `array(1=>"B",2=>"D");`

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you cannot mix associative arrays and non-associative arrays together. If you add an index to `C` like you did for everything else, it works as expected. As for strings, if they are a valid integer then it will be casted to an int [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$arr = array("0" => "A", 1 => "B", 2 => "C", 3 => "D");
// However, if you do:
$array = array(
    "0" => "A",
    1   => "B",
    "2" => array(1, 2, 3)
);
```

It shows up like you would expect in a `var_dump array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } }`